# Getting unhandled promise rejection when using batchInsert from Knex when array size is larger than 3

Tags: javascript, sql, express, knex.js

I have an express app and am using Knex as the query string builder.

When I use batch insert anticipating an array of 1000+ objects I receive an error if the array is too long (I pasted the exact error further down the question)

if I have 3 or fewer objects in my testFields array, the data inserts into the database correctly, anything greater than 3 and I receive the error. So, I believe, for some reason, the problem is the number of elements on the array.

I've isolated the problem by capturing the data to be inserted and hardcoding it.  The variable ***testFields***, which is being used as the data in the batchInsert can be found at the bottom of this question.

My database is being hosted on Azure.

My current node version is **v12.18.0.**

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "expressjs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/identity": "^1.0.3",
    "@azure/keyvault-keys": "^4.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "azure-keyvault": "^3.0.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.3",
    "express-jwt-authz": "^2.4.0",
    "express-ws": "^4.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.8.0",
    "knex": "^0.20.15",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "ms-rest-azure": "^3.0.0",
    "mssql": "^5.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "tedious": "^6.7.0",
    "ws": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my code from the Express route and Knex query.

```
const isolateProblem = (res) => {
  // need to get connection string from vault
  return getKnexWithConString
    .then((knex) => {
      return knex
        .batchInsert("Tasks", testFields)
        .returning("pk_Tasks")
        .then((result) => {
          res.send("okay");
          return result;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.send("not okay 1");
          console.log("err", err);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send("not okay");
      console.log("err2:", err);
    });
};

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await isolateProblem(res);
  console.log("data", data);
});
```

This is the error I'm receiving if my array is any larger than 3 objects.  It seems to be an unhandled promise warning originating from the transaction.js:45:38.  Not sure what I'm doing to cause this.

> "(node:805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot assign
>   to read-only property 'originalError' of object 'TransactionError:
>   Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state'
>       at ...node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/transaction.js:45:38 (node:805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection.
>
> This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
>   rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1) (node:805) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code."

The below variable the shape of the objects being inserted.  Please note, I have obscured field names and values for privacy reasons.

Also, this array has 4 elements on it so it would receive the error above.  If I was to remove any one of these elements so the array length was 3, it would have no issue inserting the data.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
const testFields = [
  {
    SqlField1: "00000",
    SqlField2: "",
    SqlField3: null,
    SqlField4: null,
    SqlField5: "UUID",
    SqlField6: null,
    SqlField7: "",
    SqlField8: "",
    SqlField9: "UUID",
    SqlField10: "Name",
    SqlField11: "",
    SqlField12: "",
    SqlField13: "",
    SqlField14: "",
    SqlField15: true,
    SqlField16: true,
    SqlField17: "UUID",
    SqlField18: "status",
    SqlField19: null,
    SqlField20: null,
    SqlField21: "###",
    SqlField22: "###",
    SqlField23: "###",
    SqlField24: null,
    SqlField25: false,
    SqlField26: null,
    SqlField27: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField28: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField29: "userName",
    SqlField30: "userName",
  },
  {
    SqlField1: "00000",
    SqlField2: "",
    SqlField3: null,
    SqlField4: null,
    SqlField5: "UUID",
    SqlField6: null,
    SqlField7: "",
    SqlField8: "",
    SqlField9: "UUID",
    SqlField10: "Name",
    SqlField11: "",
    SqlField12: "",
    SqlField13: "",
    SqlField14: "",
    SqlField15: true,
    SqlField16: true,
    SqlField17: "UUID",
    SqlField18: "status",
    SqlField19: null,
    SqlField20: null,
    SqlField21: "###",
    SqlField22: "###",
    SqlField23: "###",
    SqlField24: null,
    SqlField25: false,
    SqlField26: null,
    SqlField27: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField28: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField29: "userName",
    SqlField30: "userName",
  },
  {
    SqlField1: "00000",
    SqlField2: "",
    SqlField3: null,
    SqlField4: null,
    SqlField5: "UUID",
    SqlField6: null,
    SqlField7: "",
    SqlField8: "",
    SqlField9: "UUID",
    SqlField10: "Name",
    SqlField11: "",
    SqlField12: "",
    SqlField13: "",
    SqlField14: "",
    SqlField15: true,
    SqlField16: true,
    SqlField17: "UUID",
    SqlField18: "status",
    SqlField19: null,
    SqlField20: null,
    SqlField21: "###",
    SqlField22: "###",
    SqlField23: "###",
    SqlField24: null,
    SqlField25: false,
    SqlField26: null,
    SqlField27: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField28: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField29: "userName",
    SqlField30: "userName",
  },
  {
    SqlField1: "00000",
    SqlField2: "",
    SqlField3: null,
    SqlField4: null,
    SqlField5: "UUID",
    SqlField6: null,
    SqlField7: "",
    SqlField8: "",
    SqlField9: "UUID",
    SqlField10: "Name",
    SqlField11: "",
    SqlField12: "",
    SqlField13: "",
    SqlField14: "",
    SqlField15: true,
    SqlField16: true,
    SqlField17: "UUID",
    SqlField18: "status",
    SqlField19: null,
    SqlField20: null,
    SqlField21: "###",
    SqlField22: "###",
    SqlField23: "###",
    SqlField24: null,
    SqlField25: false,
    SqlField26: null,
    SqlField27: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField28: new Date(Date.now()),
    SqlField29: "userName",
    SqlField30: "userName",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Running into the same issue, I've done some generic tests to find ,
that the behaviour depends on the number and  maybe size of the paramters used in the batchinsert.**

A data array a = [{"a":1,"b":"1"},...] of size 64 is inserted correctly with no error.
Adding one element {"a":1,"b":"1"} is causing the error.

**It might be that 128 parameters for the underlying prepared statement is the limit that
finally makes up the root cause for the failure ? ! ?**

- "knex": "^0.20.11"
- "mssql": "^5.1.1"
- node v12.14.1

I either have to

- Slice my Data into chuncks that can be handled with batchinsert **:-(**
- Directly move to singleton inserts **:-((**
- Forget about Knex / Nodejs and return to Java,... **:-(((**

Comment: In the above context the same limits show up with knex.insert